# Visual Basic: How to create a sub the resets a button

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to create a sub that allows me to reset a button. I will have many buttons and would like to just call a sub into the buttons to make my code cleaner.  could someone guide me on how to do this i would really appreciate it

```
Private Sub Button2_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseDown, Button1.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then

        btn = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        ButtonReset()

    End If


End Sub
Public Sub ButtonReset()
    Select Case MsgBox("Do you want to reset?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel, "caption")
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            btn2_Count = 0
            MyInterval = 1
            Button2.Text = "Station 2"
            Button2.BackColor = DefaultBackColor
        Case MsgBoxResult.Cancel
            Exit Sub
        Case MsgBoxResult.No
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You've got the `Button` already in the event handler.  It's assigned to the `btn` variable.  Pass that variable to `ButtonReset` and an argument and then use the parameter in the method.

Comment: What is the point of that `Select Case`? You explicitly give the user three choices and then treat two of them exactly the same way, by doing nothing.  Just give the user two choices and then use a `If` statement to determine whether they chose the one you want to act on.

Answer (score 0):

As @jmcilhinney mentioned above, no need to use `Select Case`.

I'll write a little example here, may be of help. However, I won't include the

```
btn2_Count = 0
MyInterval = 1
```

as I'm not 100% what they are.

There's another thing that stands out. You seem to have btn as a button (either of the buttons) then call a sub that is hard-coded to button2. Seems to defeat the whole point.

With my answer I'm assuming you want "Station 1" for button1 and "Station 2" for button2? **You can pre-load a number into the button's '.Tag' property and use that to determine which button is being dealt with**.

So for example, something like:

```
Private Sub Button_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseDown, Button2.MouseDown
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to reset?", "Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
            btn.Text = String.Format("Station {0}", btn.Tag.ToString)
            btn.BackColor = DefaultBackColor
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: how does this line work ?  btn.Text = String.Format("Station {0}", btn.Tag.ToString)

Comment: I'm getting this error, System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: In the above example `btn.Text = String.Format("Station {0}", btn.Tag.ToString)` is the equivalent `btn.Text = "Station " & btn.Tag.ToString`. Your `NullReferenceException` will occur if you didn't pre set the `.Tag` property. Did you do that? You can either look for the Tag property in the designer's button properties or, for example, put this in your Form_Load event to test: `Button1.Tag = 1
         Button2.Tag = 2`